# Move column to the left in excel with openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

with openpyxl can we move column 'EE' to column 'CC'

[image]

it should look like below excel

[image]

here column 'EE' moved to 'CC' place and 'CC' automatically moved ahead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move it as a range.

1. Insert a new column at Column CC
2. Move the range in Column EE (Note after step 1 this is now Column EF)
3. Delete Column EF

The following example takes the move to and from columns and determines Column numbers and offsets to move the data.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils.cell import column_index_from_string as cifs
from openpyxl.worksheet.cell_range import CellRange

xlfile = 'foo.xlsx'

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(xlfile)
ws = wb['Sheet1']

### Set to and from Columns
column_to_shift = 'CC'  # Column to copy data to
column_to_move = 'EE'  # Column to copy data from

insert_column = cifs(column_to_shift)  # Column number for new column insert (Column CC) i.e. 81
offset_column_number = cifs(column_to_move)+1  # Column number of data after new Column inserted (Column EF) 136

### Get range of the data to be copied at offset column, 'EF2:EF8'
copy_range = CellRange(min_col=offset_column_number, min_row=2, max_col=offset_column_number, max_row=8).coord

ws.insert_cols(insert_column)  # Insert new column at column_to_shift

ws.move_range(copy_range, cols=insert_column - offset_column_number)  # Move data in range from EF to CC

ws.delete_cols(offset_column_number)  # Delete empty Column (Column EF i.e. 136) 

wb.save('foo_out.xlsx')
```

Comment: can we do this if 'EE' is find in excel then shift it to 'CC' place or  ws['C'] place

Comment: It doesn't matter which column(s) is being moved and to where, I just used Column E to Column C as the example. If you dont know what number Column 'CC' or 'EE" is or want the app to determine these values, you can use the utils of either Openpyxl or Xlsxwriter that convert Column letter to number.

Comment: yes like you said, i don't know what column number of "EE" so could you please give me one example that what if i got "EE" in column list so move that column to number 3

Comment: You can use the Openpyxl util `openpyxl.utils.cell.column_index_from_string`. I have updated the code sample so it takes the two columns 'CC" and ''EE" and calculates the columns and offsets to move the data.